# Getting additional keyword information from item Xml?

Tags: tom.net, templating

I have a very generic "GetItemXml" template building block that basically reads the current item being rendered and outputs the item's xml to the delivery tier.

```
Component component = (Component)engine.GetObject(package.GetByName(Package.ComponentName));
output = package.CreateXmlDocumentItem(
           ContentType.Xml,component.ToXml(XmlFormat.R6Native, XmlSections.All)
                                                                .OwnerDocument);
```

This outputs the xml correctly, but keyword fields are output like this:

```
<ContentCategory>tridion</ContentCategory>
<ContentCategory>tridion2009</ContentCategory>
```

Is there any way - short of controlling the XML output myself - to ask Tridion to include additional information in the XML like an xlink:href to the keyword ID?

Comment: This answer from @KahTang on [StackOverlow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980316/how-can-i-get-the-key-of-a-keyword-from-an-xslt-tbb/12780807) is nice as well, though. Then you can use it in your Dreamweaver or xslt Templating as well.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You just need to `Load` component with proper `LoadFlags`, like this:

```
Component component = (Component)engine.GetObject(package.GetByName(Package.ComponentName));
component.Load(LoadFlags.KeywordXlinks);
output = package.CreateXmlDocumentItem(
    ContentType.Xml,component.ToXml(XmlFormat.R6Native, XmlSections.All).OwnerDocument);
```

It will look like this:

```
<keyword xlink:href="tcm:2-83-1024" xlink:title="b" 
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">b</keyword>
```

See **[Coreservice and ReadOptions](http://amarchuk.blogspot.nl/2012/10/coreservice-and-readoptions.html)** for more info about `LoadFlags`

Comment: Awesome answer - Really wish I had know this when we built the XSLT Mediator for R5.3

Comment: What? Why is this not in any manual? This has been an issue since R5.3, and people have been coming up with crazy stuff to get this information...

Comment: Awesome. I now get <ContentCategory xlink:href="tcm:5-239-1024" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="tridion 2011">tridion 2011</ContentCategory>

Comment: Something about Tridion Nuno didn't know. I'm shocked!

Comment: @user978511, you should update this [Stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980316/how-can-i-get-the-key-of-a-keyword-from-an-xslt-tbb/12780807) as well, Or redirect it to this answer when the site goes live!

Comment: I remember a bunch of helper functions to get that information in additional lines of code... all messy. Great answer!