# How to Get Keyword from Metadata or Item XML Using Core Service

Tags: core-service

When working with the Core Service I am loading item XML that has Keywords inside and I need to replace some Keywords with others.  Unfortunately the XML lists only the keyword name and not the tcm link to the Keyword item.

How can I get the Keyword object from the XML?

```
OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData filter = new OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData
{
    ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Page }
};
filter.Recursive = true;

var pageXml = client.GetListXml(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SgTcmId"], filter);

//loop through each item and find out if it is the product we want
foreach (var pageElem in pageXml.Elements())
{
    string id = pageElem.Attribute("ID").Value;
    var pageData = (PageData)client.TryCheckOut(id, null);
    //...quick-and-dirty code for my eyes only...
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nuno had started this topic for Tom.net in another question: [Getting additional keyword information from item Xml?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/38/getting-additional-keyword-information-from-item-xml).  It's the same for Core Service.

Need to use LoadFlags as follows:

```
ReadOptions readOptions = new ReadOptions();
readOptions.LoadFlags = LoadFlags.KeywordXlinks;

...

var pageData = (PageData)client.TryCheckOut(id, readOptions);
```