# Format for setting Keywords in Components with CoreService

Tags: core-service

I see how read options let you choose how to choose how to *read* fields in a Component's XML: [How to Get Keyword from Metadata or Item XML Using Core Service](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/3267/46).

I'm having a hard time finding an example for saving a Component over the Core Service with Keywords. Do we use text or tcm-ids for Keywords (in text fields set to a Category)?

Answer (score 3):

So assuming you are having Component Xml prepared to be saved using Core Service. You would be doing something like below:

```
var component = client.GetDefaultData(ItemType.Component, containerId) as ComponentData;

                component.Title = title;
                component.Schema = new LinkToSchemaData { IdRef = schemaId };
                component.Content = contentXml;
client.Create(component, DefaultReadOptions)
```

In `contentXml` there will be the xml elements for the Text Fields using Keywords. And those are nothing but Text Fields in Tridion.

So if you set the inner text for those elements to the Keyword Title, the Components should be saved. 
I have run this code in Tridion 2011.

So as Peter mentioned in his answer, if you set somthing like this

```
<myKeywordField>keyword Title</myKeywordField>
```

Tridion will convert it as below according to the schema by setting the additional attributes.

```
<myKeywordField xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="tcm:13-366-1024" xlink:title="keyword Title">keyword Title</myKeywordField>
```

Comment: Excellent. We just need to make sure the text is a valid Keyword Title (for that Publication).

Comment: Yeah correct, else it will result in a exception.

Answer (score 3):

You use the TCM URI of the Keyword and you set it in an **xlink:href** attribute.

(The *xlink:type* and *xlink:title* attributes are optional and will be set automatically for you if you don't include them)

For example:

```
<SeeAlso xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="tcm:1-261"></SeeAlso>
```

Just like with other fields, this is inside of the XML stored in the *Content* property. How you create the XML is up to you, but I recommend using LINQ to XML (XDocument, XElement, etc.)

Comment: I just checked that the "xlink:href=tcm:x-y-z" is added automatically as well. I am doing it in 2013 sp1

Comment: Okay, so it's _either_ text or TCM URI? Does the text inside the text node (e.g. Value in `<SeeAlso>Value</SeeAlso>`) count?

Comment: And good tip on LINQ--we had a minor issue with using the right namespace for embedded fields with plain old `XMLDocument` (it should be the same as the Schema, oops).

Comment: I actually didn't know that it also can look it up by the title. Very handy. So you can choose whether you want to refer to the Keyword by its ID or its title.

Answer (score 2):

I have written the below code for Localizing and Updating a list of Components in a specific publication; this may help in getting some idea of handling the Keywords - So if a Keyword does not exists, it will create it through core service before creating the component and so there is no exception: (This code is for update but can provide help in getting startup code for handling Keyword scenario)

```
public List<string> LocalizeAndUpdateComponent(List<ComponentXMLs> components, string targetPubID)
        {
            List<string> successList = new List<string>();

            foreach (ComponentXMLs xml in components)
            {
                try
                {
                    string tcmURI = xml.TCMURI;
                    TcmUri oldURI = new TcmUri(tcmURI);
                    ItemType type = oldURI.ItemType;
                    if (type == ItemType.Component)
                    {
                        string oldPubURI = oldURI.ContextRepositoryId.ToString();
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tcmURI))
                        {
                            tcmURI = tcmURI.Substring(tcmURI.IndexOf('-'));

                        }
                        string localizedURI = string.Concat("tcm:", targetPubID, tcmURI);

                        ComponentData component = (ComponentData)client.Read(localizedURI, new ReadOptions());

                        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                        doc.LoadXml(xml.ComponentXML);

                        if (doc.DocumentElement != null && doc.DocumentElement.Attributes != null)
                        {
                            doc.DocumentElement.RemoveAttribute("xmlns");
                        }


                        XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
                        ns.AddNamespace("tcm", "http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0");
                        ns.AddNamespace("xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
                        ns.AddNamespace("xhtml", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
                        ns.AddNamespace("xmlns: tcmi", "http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0/Instance");
                        SchemaData schemaData = (SchemaData)client.Read(component.Schema.IdRef, new ReadOptions());
                        Dictionary<string, string> keywordFields = GetKeywordFields(component.Schema.IdRef, targetPubID);
                        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValue in keywordFields)
                        {
                            var keywords = client.GetList(keyValue.Key, new KeywordsFilterData());

                            foreach (KeywordData keyword in keywords)
                            {
                                XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes(string.Concat(schemaData.RootElementName, "/", keyValue.Value), ns);
                                keyword.Title = nodes != null && nodes.Count > 0 ? nodes[0].InnerText : keyword.Title;


                                if (keyword.BluePrintInfo.IsLocalized != null && keyword.BluePrintInfo.IsLocalized == false)
                                {
                                    client.Localize(keyword.Id, new ReadOptions());
                                }

                                if (!keyword.LockInfo.LockType.Value.HasFlag(LockType.CheckedOut))
                                {
                                    client.CheckOut(keyword.Id, true, new ReadOptions());
                                }
                                client.Save(keyword, new ReadOptions());
                                client.CheckIn(keyword.Id, new ReadOptions());
                            }
                        }

                        if (component.BluePrintInfo.IsLocalized != null && component.BluePrintInfo.IsLocalized == false)
                        {
                            client.Localize(localizedURI, new ReadOptions());
                        }

                        component.Content = xml.ComponentXML.Replace("tcm:" + oldPubURI, "tcm:" + targetPubID);


                        if (!component.LockInfo.LockType.Value.HasFlag(LockType.CheckedOut))
                        {
                            client.CheckOut(localizedURI, true, new ReadOptions());
                        }

                        client.Save(component, new ReadOptions());

                        client.CheckIn(localizedURI, new ReadOptions());
                        successList.Add(localizedURI + " - Localized Successfully");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    successList.Add(xml.TCMURI + " - Error in Localizing");
                }
            }

            return successList;
        }
```