# How to read keyword tcm ID?

Tags: 2011, taxonomy

I have a Component which contains category keywords as a drop down field.
Editors can choose the desired keyword from the drop down.
Following is the component source:

```
<Filter xmlns="uuid:ceca6b4d-5ffa-4012-ab77-2b6c9fdb0ab0">
   <Languages>
       <Language_Names>
           <Language_Name xlink:href="tcm:201-24156-1024" xlink:title="English" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">English</Language_Name>
       </Language_Names>
       <Language_Names>
           <Language_Name xlink:href="tcm:201-24183-1024" xlink:title="Arabic" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">Arabic</Language_Name>
       </Language_Names>
       <InputBox_Type>DropDown</InputBox_Type>
   </Languages>
</Filter>
```

In DWT I want to read TCM ID of the keyword. It seems I need to write a C# Template Building Block.

Is there any code reference available which will help me to start my C# TBB?

Is there any Tridion extension which will give me the TCM ID?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Get Keyword from Metadata or Item XML Using Core Service](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3267/how-to-get-keyword-from-metadata-or-item-xml-using-core-service)

Comment: I don't think the Core Service is mentioned anyway. It seems to be a DWT question. @user844 Could you tidy up your question please so it's clear what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5):

You just need to read your component with the correct `ReadOptions`. See:
[How to Get Keyword from Metadata or Item XML Using Core Service](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3267/how-to-get-keyword-from-metadata-or-item-xml-using-core-service/3268#3268)
and [Getting additional keyword information from item Xml?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/38/getting-additional-keyword-information-from-item-xml)