# Get Keyword Id from Content of Component

Tags: core-service, 2013-sp1

I need to write an application which requires me to get all keywords out of a given component.

So if I have following schema:

```
text_field_1 : KeywordFieldDefinitionData, Category (tcm:x-y-z, CATEGORY1)
text_field_2 : KeywordFieldDefinitionData, Category (tcm:a-b-c, CATEGORY2)
random_field_random: .. .. (does not matter)
```

When I have a Component for the given schema

```
text_field_1 : Antwerpen : tcm:e-b-c
text_field_2 : Hasselt : tcm:f-g-h
random_field_random: asdasasd
```

I need to convert this to:

```
[
   {
       Id: tcm:e-b-c,
       Value: Antwerpen,
       Category: CATEGORY1
   },
   {
       Id: tcm:f-g-h,
       Value: Hasselt,
       Category: CATEGORY2
   },
]
```

To do this I need the Tcm value of the keyword that is chosen in the fields. But when I look at the xml document from the component (through Core Service) I see the field as:

```
<text_field_1 xmlns=\"uuid:37a7a47f-88c8-44f7-a6e8-5900ae9f985e\">Antwerpen</text_field_1>
```

Is there a way to get the keyword Id without going through all keywords within the given Category?

BTW: If I look at the Content Xml through Anguilla I see following Field Value:

```
<text_field_1 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="tcm:e-b-c" xlink:title="Antwerpen">Antwerpen</text_field_1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read your component with correct `LoadFlags`, namely `LoadFlags.KeywordXlinks`. See: 
http://amarchuk.blogspot.nl/2012/10/coreservice-and-readoptions.html
or [Getting additional keyword information from item Xml?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/38/getting-additional-keyword-information-from-item-xml)